# Possible to add proxy after TOR exit node?

Tags: proxy, tor, whonix, proxychains

Can I configure the TOR Browser which comes with Whonix to use a proxy,
so that it becomes an extra hop **after** the TOR exit node?

Connecting as follows:
Browser(workstation) > TOR(gateway) > exit node > proxy

Effectively rendering it a proxychain.

In contrast to the Tor Browser Bundle which connects to TOR via 127.0.0.1 under Whonix we have a different situation where we connect through the gateway to TOR. So a connection like I described maybe this might be possible.

Is there any more recommended solution for proxy chaining under Whonix?

Answer (score 3):

> Can I configure the TOR Browser which comes with Whonix to use a proxy, so that it becomes an extra hop after the TOR exit node?

Yes.

> Connecting as follows: Browser(workstation) > TOR(gateway) > exit node > proxy

Or in other words: 
user -> Tor -> Proxy -> Destination

> In contrast to the Tor Browser Bundle which connects to TOR via 127.0.0.1 under Whonix we have a different situation where we connect through the gateway to TOR. So a connection like I described maybe this might be possible.

Yes.

> Is there any more recommended solution for proxy chaining under Whonix?

See also: 
[Whonix Tunnel Documentation](https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Features#VPN_.2F_Tunnel_support)

Full disclosure: 
I am a maintainer of Whonix.